# Getting only "today and yseterday" from ngx-moment in angular 9

Tags: angularjs, typescript, momentjs

I'm using ngx-moment pipe to display my date

it's really helpful and very useful

But I want to display the date from today and tomorrow and then the calendar date  like that
if the date today then "Today and 00:00pm", it tomorrow then "Yesterday at 00:00pm",

Then if the day after tomorrow I need to show the calendar date "13/9/2020"

here is the code

```
date:'2020-09-13T00:00:00' ;

<div>Last updated: {{date| amTimeAgo}}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it

```
moment.updateLocale('en', {
    calendar : {
        lastDay : '[Yesterday] LT',
        sameDay : '[Today] LT',
        nextDay : 'LL',
        lastWeek : 'LL',
        nextWeek : 'LL',
        sameElse : 'LL'
    }
});
```